# WebView cocoa reloading webpage

Tags: cocoa, webview, osx-snow-leopard

I have created a mac application using the WebView. But issue is that webView is reloading when

```
[webView mainFrameUrl] == newURL
```

why this problem is happening?? how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the fact that the answer of theAmateurProgrammer is the correct one I want to give you another suggestion if it didn't solve your problem (since you didn't accept it).

Don't call mainFrameUrl frequently. Call it once and store it in another variable in the delegate method `- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame`

Comment: What is the reason behind avoiding call to mainFrameURL ? How would storing it in a variable be more efficient ??

Answer (score 1):

Never compare strings with `==` You always use NSString's `isEqualToString:` method to check if the 2 strings are equal.

```
[[webView mainFrameURL] isEqualToString: newURL]
```